# Errors building PCL 1.8 with VTK-7.0.0

Tags: cmake, vtk, point-cloud-library

Trying to build PCL 1.8 using VTK 7.0.0.  Target is Visual Studio 2015.
Using the VTK OpenGL2 backend I got errors similar to those reported [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Building-PCL-1-8-0-issue-vtkgl-missing-td4040453.html) and [here](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Migrating-from-OpenGL-to-OpenGL2-td5735123.html) which indicate OpenGL2 is not supported for PCL yet.

However, using the original VTK OpenGL backend I get different errors:

- The list of VTK libraries PCL projects link against includes libraries whose names suggest both OpenGL and OpenGL2, even though VTK is only configured with one or the other backend.  For example, "vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2.lib" (when VTK backend is OpenGL).
- "vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2.lib" does not exist, causing a linker error.  However, a library called "vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2-7.0.lib" exists, so it appears a version suffix is added when VTK is built, but is not added when CMake generates the list of libraries to link PCL projects with.
- `vtkVertexBufferObject.cxx(104): error C2039: 'GetExtensionManager': is not a member of 'vtkOpenGLRenderWindow'`.  Class `vtkOpenGLRenderWindow` is suspiciously tagged with `VTKRENDERINGOPENGL2_EXPORT` (again in an OpenGL build).

I don't know whether the problem lies in VTK or PCL.  The CMake build system is completely opaque to me so I am getting nowhere with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just following up to myself (again)...

The problem was that, because I had initially built the "INSTALL" project of VTK using the OpenGL2 backend, then changed the backend to OpenGL and built the "INSTALL" project of VTK again, both backends existed in the install folder.  VTKConfig.cmake (which PCL uses to link with VTK) finds and links against all modules that it finds in the install folder, thus attempting to link against both incompatible backends.

The VTK build system does not detect that conflicting modules are already present when installing, and the "make clean" or "rebuild" options don't remove conflicting modules (VTK does not have an uninstaller).  Deleting CMake caches, or creating a new clean build directory, is not sufficient to clear up this mess.

So the only solution was to **manually find and delete the VTK install folder** ("C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK", for the record) if you need to change the VTK backend.